# How to create Pin Pad as matrix in R?

Tags: r

I am working on some robotics problem and I want to create an ATM Pin Pad in form of a matrix

So far I could think of is

```
items = 10;
width = 3;

x <- 1:9
length(x) <- prod(dim(matrix(x, ncol = width)))
## you will get a warning here unless suppressWarnings() is used except for width = 3
Pad = matrix(x, ncol = width, byrow = TRUE)

if(width == 1)
  Pad = rbind(Pad, c(0))

if(width == 9)
  Pad = cbind(Pad, c(0))`
```

The problem I am facing is that the width can be a variable quantity and thus placing zero at the end(after 9) is creating a problem. Also, if somehow I put a zero which will always be in the last row, anything after 0 should be -1, -2 and so on till the row is full as they will not be considered in the graph to form

Example:
I have handled the cases explicitly for width 1 and 9 now
if the width is 3 I need something like

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
 0 -1 -2
```

if the width is 4

```
 1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 0 -1 -2
```

if the width is 5

```
 1 2 3 4 5
 6 7 8 9 0
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: The code above does *not* produce a warning (R-3.5.3) with `width <- 3` as you have defined here.

Comment: Yes because you get 3 rows and 3 cols to fit in 9 values

Comment: I said that suggesting your comment/code were inconsistent/inaccurate. I see what you are intending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple/small helper function:

```r
mypad <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  if (missing(nrow)) nrow <- ceiling(10L / ncol)
  if (missing(ncol)) ncol <- ceiling(10L / nrow)
  x <- c(1:9, 0L)
  length(x) <- prod(nrow, ncol)
  x[ is.na(x) ] <- -seq_len(sum(is.na(x)))
  matrix(x, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

Use:

```r
mypad(ncol=3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    7    8    9
# [4,]    0   -1   -2
mypad(ncol=4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    5    6    7    8
# [3,]    9    0   -1   -2
mypad(ncol = 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    7    8    9
# [4,]    0   -1   -2
mypad(ncol = 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    5    6    7    8
# [3,]    9    0   -1   -2
mypad(ncol = 5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    6    7    8    9    0
mypad(ncol = 6)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
# [2,]    7    8    9    0   -1   -2
```